# Accounting for drop-outs in clinical trials

Tags: statistics, error-propagation, experimental-mathematics

'Physical Therapy Review' [Intention to treat analysis, compliance, drop-outs and how to deal with missing data in clinical research: a review
Susan Armijo-Olivo, Sharon Warren and David Magee
Faculty of Rehabilitation Medicine, University of Alberta, Edmonton, Canada] suggests a number of ways to account for drop-outs in trials, but remark that none are beyond criticism.

I wondered whether this method would be good, and I'm interested in critique:

If you have an experiment with D valid data points and O drop outs, and the D valid data points have a mean of M and a standard deviation of σ then:

You can, but shouldn't, assume that M and σ are similar for O - there's a reason for the drop-outs that might make them significantly different.

If we look at the extreme with D = 0 and O = 1, M=0 and σ = 0 - but the probability of the result being accurate, valid or reliable, R = 0. To reflect this, we could say that M=0 and σ(corrected) = big integer (a massive variance).

At the other extreme, with D = N (a very large number >10000, say) and O=0, M=m1 and σ=s1, with R -> 1 (say .95 or so). We can, fairly safely, say that σ(corrected) = s1.

A real study is somewhere in between. A mid-point of a distribution of studies would be:

D=N/2 O=N/2 M=m2 σ=s2 it seems reasonable to say that R ≈ .5. What can we say about σ? Well, it is very unlikely be s2, but it's not likely to be as massive a difference as in case 1. Would it be reasonable to set σ(corrected) = σ + (2σ / m ) - the reasoning being that the unreliability is likely to be in the order of sigma relative to the mean?

If so, then for arbitrary D and O,

σ(corrected) = σ + ( O / (D+O))(σ / m)

Comment: Cross Validated SE might be a better place for this question.

Comment: There's a large literature in economics on "partial identification" which deals with problems like this. The idea is to take the extreme cases and then say that the parameter falls somewhere in between. Then as you add assumptions, you can further restrict the parameter. See Chuck Manski.

Comment: Great, thank you, so I'm on the right track. I'll look up partial identification.

Comment: Where is 'Cross Validated SE'?